# PHP RESTful routing

Tags: php, rest, mod-rewrite

My problem is pretty straight forward. I am implementing RESTful services in PHP, and I am using mod-rewrite to redirect the clean URLs to and index.php. So for example, if I have this url for getting the course having the code 12345.

`http://localhost/courses/12345` I will redirect this to index.php in the following structure

```
http://localhost/index.php?manager=CoursesManager&courseCode=12345
```

and in index.php I look up the CoursesManager.php, and if I am able to find it, I create a CourseManager object and then process the query string and call the method I need.

But if for instance I want to get let's say the types of class that a Course can have, I don't know how to rewrite the url. Let's say the url would be

```
http://localhost/courses/12345/typesofclass
```

How could I rewrite it?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you should look into a more generalized PHP router than custom rewrite rules for every single action. For example: http://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router

Comment: My two cents, I used this router extensively: https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router

Comment: So hould would I actually map it using these routers? It's still not clear to me. Let's say I have a method getTypesOfClassForCourse($courseCode) in the CoursesManager class. How can I use these to call my method when the above url is requested?

Comment: Given the router I like to above, you use `$r->add('/courses/:id', ...)` for the first URL and `$r->add('/courses/:id/typesofclass', ...)` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule /courses/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]*) /index.php?manager=CoursesManager&courseCode=$1&type=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the best is to create an all over url rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and create a specific entry in the database:

```
+----+-----------------------------+
| id | clean_url                   |
+----+-----------------------------+
|  1 | /courses/12345              |
|  2 | /courses/12345/typesofclass |
+----+-----------------------------+
```

Now, you just fetch the url, look into db what id it is for and load the required data/script.

You can alos add, the *old* url to that, if you want:

```
+----+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | clean_url                   | old_url                                    |
+----+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | /courses/12345              | manager=CoursesManager&courseCode=12345    |
|  2 | /courses/12345/typesofclass | manager=CoursesManager&courseCode=12345&.. |
+----+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Now, if you still need to know the *old* parameters, you can just add a small script **at the very top of your `index.php` file** like this:

```
SELECT old_url FROM ... WHERE clean_url = '{$your_url}'
$params = explode( '&', $result_of_query );
foreach ( $params as $value )
{
    $gets = explode( '=', $value );
    $_GET[$gets[0]] = $gets[1];
}
```

This will set your get parameters at the start of your page and the script should work as before.

Comment: I kind of understand. But how should my query string look so I can figure out to what method to point in my CoursesManager class? I see you appended at the end of the query string "&.", what does that actually mean?

Comment: The `&` is just ment to be a 3rd parameter, like `&typesof=class` etc. PS: added to the answer